# Cucumber: Scenario Outline - Accessing the data table at run time

Tags: cucumber, bdd

In our cucumber feature file, we are using scenario outline, and we have requirement before running script to populate data at run time.

Based on the city route being passed in the data file, we create PNR using a API which returns me a actual PNR. PNR value created need to be stored in the scenario data table.

If we have Scenario, we can use the DataTable function to access the values inside function. Do we have any class to interact with scenario outline data table

e.g.

```
Scenario Outline:
  Given user have opened the application
  And verifies if lookup page is loaded successfully
  Then enter <ConfirmationNumber> as confirmation number
  Then enter <LastName> as last name

Examples:
  |DepartureCity|ArrivalCity|PNR|PassengerName|
  |BAH          |AUH        |   |BRUCE WAYNe  |
```

If you notice, i'm not passing PNR value in the feature file, based on route being passed, PNR is created at run time with flight available at that time.

So its must for me to populate the PNR field with value being created. Not just value, flight time also need to be populated.

Kindly let me know if existing class or alternative to solve this issue.

Comment: If you cannot know what to expect before your test starts, you haven't designed the test properly. Why can't you know what the PNR will be? Probably because you are not in control of the data that is used to create the PNR. To properly design a test, you need to control in the input values, whether by ORM data injection to control what the PNR will be, or by mocking a server that provides the PNR, or something along those lines.

Comment: @Dave McNulla : The problem is, for all my test case, input is PNR, so i need to create a PNR at run time for the next flight available for the route passed. This is something i cannot control. If i try to manual enter the PNR for each test case, it wont hold any good automating the test case

Comment: If you try to test something that you cannot control, then you cannot control the result.

Comment: Ram can you accept my answer

Answer (score 1):

The answer simply is the design - do it either of the two ways

1. Ensure you have a background  generating the PNR number , pass it on
   to next steps via a variable, put the variable name under PNR Number column and use it as eval(variable) in your step .
2. Insert a step to generate it - ie you are not taking any arguments here, pass it to next needed steps. do same as above - eval the variable name.